# Перехват пакета на python

Tags: python

Всем привет! Решил напписать антивирус (курсовая). Делаю я его на python (это программа типа сетевого демона). Прикол в том, чтобы он работал в фоновом режиме. Есть, к примеру, вредоносные ссылки. И мне нужно перехватывать, например, http/https запрос из ПК и, если, ссылка вредоносная, то предупредить юзера. Как это реализовать?

Comment: Для перехвата пакетов на питоне используйте scapy. Основной вопрос - как вы будете определять вредоносная ссылка или нет?

Answer (score 2):

Шаг 1. Перехват пакетов. Можно использовать модуль scapy.
Если есть охота возится в перехватом на уровне сокетов -  то модуль socket.
Если по каким-то причинам они не подходят - есть и другие аналогичные пакеты (libmproxy, pypcap и т.д.)

Шаг 2. Распарсиваем каждый пакет. Если вас интересуют только http -  отбираем (фильтруем) их из всего потока. В упомянутой модуле scapy есть возможность это сделать. В остальных -  надо смотреть.

Шаг 3. Определение вредноносная-ли ссылка - ну это вам виднее, как вы собрались это реализовывать. Но раз вы пишете "Есть, к примеру, вредоносные ссылки" -  значит считаем, что они у вас действительно есть.

В чем заключается прикольность того, что ваш скрипт должен работать в фоновом режиме - не понял.